# Auto Increment value according to previous

Tags: mysql

When i delete one record from mysql table and insert new one on that place that time it is setting the auto increment column value to next i had inserted lastly which is not expected

I googled it on many sites but not getting exact result that i want 
I also tried by setting last_inserted_id()+1 as follows:

```
Alter table t1 auto_increment = last_insert_id() + 1;
```

But it is showing error

I want to set that value next to previous record's auto increment value,

Please Help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why* do you want to do this?  The contract of an auto increment column does not say that the `id` will always follow the next sequential value.  It only says that it will always be unique, and generally increasing.

If you want to generate a sequence, use something like `ROW_NUMBER` (in MySQL versions 8+):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY auto_increment) AS rn
FROM yourTable;
```

Or, in earlier versions of MySQL, use user variables:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT 
    (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS rn
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY auto_increment;
```